# Cordova app selection is visible on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am making an android app with Apache Cordova app with `html`, `css` and `javascript`.. as it is, i made an HTML document and successfully made my app. In my app, but i have to fix something related to UI. When i click on a div or something with a link or button, a selection is showing up as in the picture.

[image]

For text i.e `h1` , `h2` etc, i used some handy css tricks :

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
user-select: none; /* Standard */
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it the context menu you mean?

[image]

If so, some js should do it:

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     return false;
};
```

This should work on android platform. This is also the simplest options, while some other options suggest adding a java class in the Cordova source code.